# return certain element from list else return last

Tags: python-2.7

What I'd like to get is to return a certain element from a list (say element 3). However, if that element is not/no longer in that list, then return the last (or first or second to last) element from that list. Something like this:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
my_list = [a, b, c]
if my_list[3] in my_list:
    print my_list[3]
else:
    print my_list[-1]
```

I understand the above doesn't work, but I hope it clarifies my question on how to properly get this to work. This may or may not return in a later Codecademy lesson, but this will give me sleepless nights until it gets solved (I'm sure this is recognizable with many of you).

EDIT: To perhaps clarify a little better, here's one of my comments from below:

"Let's say my list contains 15+ elements and through the course of several inputs, 10 elements have been removed (could be 5, could be 12. It all depends on the input beforehand). As a final result I'd like to print the 6th element. But, if this element is no longer available, then just print the last element in the list."

Comment: How can the element be *no longer part of the list*? `my_list[3] in my_list` should always succeed... Given the list contains three elements.

Comment: `my_list[3]` is out of range: your list has 3 elements. Did you mean `if 3 in my_list` ?

Comment: I wouldn't stop sleeping for that ...

Comment: you want: `print(3 if 3 in my_list else my_list[-1])`

Comment: let's say there was an element d before and I added `my_list.remove[d]`.

Comment: you are aware that `my_list[3]` accesses the 4th element of the list, whatever the value inside the list right?

Comment: yes, so if there is no 4th element, I'd like it to print the last element instead

Answer (score 0):

Finally found what I was looking for:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = 4
e = 5

my_list = [a, b, c, d, e]

del my_list[3]
if len(my_list) >= 4: #this is what I was looking for
    print my_list[3]
else:
    print my_list[-1]
```

Will print out 5 (e = 5)

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = 4
e = 5

my_list = [a, b, c, d, e]

del my_list[4]
del my_list[3]
if len(my_list) >= 4: #this is what I was looking for
    print my_list[3]
else:
    print my_list[-1]
```

Will print out 3 (c = 3)